# Ejecución de una función sin llamarla

Tags: python, python-3.7, decoradores

Tratando el tema de las funciones decoradoras, se ejecuta la función sin llamarla.

Código:

```
def funcion_decoradora(funcion_parametro):
    def funcion_interior():

        # Acciones adicionales que decoran
        print("Vamos a realizar un cálculo:")
        funcion_parametro()

        # Acciones adicionales que decoran
        print("Hemos terminado el cálculo")

    return funcion_interior()

@funcion_decoradora
def suma():
    print(15+20)

@funcion_decoradora   
def resta():
    print(30-10)
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
Vamos a realizar un cálculo:
35
Hemos terminado el cálculo
Vamos a realizar un cálculo:
20
Hemos terminado el cálculo
```

Sin embargo, si mi código es el siguiente:

```
def funcion_decoradora(funcion_parametro):
    def funcion_interior():

        # Acciones adicionales que decoran
        print("Vamos a realizar un cálculo:")
        funcion_parametro()

        # Acciones adicionales que decoran
        print("Hemos terminado el cálculo")

    return funcion_interior()

@funcion_decoradora
def suma():
    print(15+20)

@funcion_decoradora   
def resta():
    print(30-10)


suma()
resta()
```

El resultado es:

```
Vamos a realizar un cálculo:
35
Hemos terminado el cálculo
Vamos a realizar un cálculo:
20
Hemos terminado el cálculo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/practica_decoradores.py", line 28, in <module>
    suma()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

¿Alguien sabría porque ocurre esto?
Muchas gracias de antemano
Saludos

Answer (score 2):

## Conceptos previos

Un decorador es una función (llamémosla `g`) que:

- Recibe como parámetro otra función (llamémosla `f`)
- Devuelve como resultado otra función (llamémosla `h`)

Entonces si haces `g(f)` el resultado es `h`, que *debe ser otra función*, de modo que más adelante puedes hacer `h()` para invocarla.

Esto se completa con la sintaxis `@` que sirve para invocar un decorador, pasándole como parámetro la función que está definida a continuación, y usando el resultado devuelto para sustituir a esa función que iba a continuación. Es decir, si haces:

```
@g
def f():
   print("Soy f")
```

Lo que ocurre es que `g(f)` es invocada, y el valor retornado por ésta (lo que antes llamamos `h`) se asigna como nuevo valor para `f`. Es decir, equivale a:

```
def f():
   print("Soy f")
f = g(f)
```

Por lo que a partir de aquí, cuando llames a `f` estarás llamando en realidad a `h` (la función retornada por el decorador).

## Tu problema

Tu problema es que tu decorador `g` (en tu caso `funcion_decoradora`) no devuelve como resultado una función (tu `h` sería lo que has llamado `funcion_interior`), pues para que así fuera tendrías que haber puesto `return funcion_interior` (sin paréntesis al final).

En cambio has puesto `return funcion_interior()` (con paréntesis al final). Esto causa que se **ejecute** en ese momento esa función y que el valor retornado por esta llamada sea lo que tu decorador retorna. Ya que en este caso la ejecución de `funcion_interior()` produce como resultado `None` (pues no retorna nada), ese será el valor que estás retornando desde tu decorador.

Por eso observas dos comportamientos:

- La función `suma()` o `resta()` se llaman sin que las llames. En realidad se llaman como consecuencia del `@funcion_decoradora` que ya hemos visto que equivale a una llamada `funcion_decoradora(suma)` o `funcion_decoradora(resta)`, respectivamente, y dentro de ellas llamas a `funcion_interna()` que causará la ejecución de `suma()` o `resta()` respectivamente.
- El valor retornado por `funcion_decoradora` se asigna como nuevo valor del identificador `suma` o `resta` respectivamente, sustituyendo su definición original. Ya que según vimos estás retornando `None`, resulta que tanto `suma` como `resta` son `None` una vez decoradas. Por ello al tratar de ejecutarlas te da el error de que `NoneType` no es  *callable*

## La solución

Reemplaza `return funcion_interna()` por `return funcion_interna`